# node.js npm package commands are often broken on Windows - can this be fixed?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

There's a big problem for node.js / npm users on Windows. The problem is that many package.json scripts contain commands that are platform specific.

On of the biggest specific problems is commands that set an environment variable and run a command, at the same time. This syntax is not compatible with Windows. There is an example below extracted from a package.json rife with the problem.

So the question is, how can I transform package.json scripts from being Unix compatible to being Windows compatible, in terms of setting environment variables?

I'm wondering if there is a general solution rather than the current manual solution which is to edit the package.json and change all the commands from Unix to Windows compatible.

A further problem of course being that on Windows, environment variables are set in a different way depending on whether you are using Powershell or cmd.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel/register --recursive --require ./test/setup.js $(find test -name '*.spec.js')",
    "test-watch": "npm test -- --watch",
    "test-e2e:crdv": "chromedriver",
    "test-e2e": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --compilers js:babel/register --require ./test/setup.js --require co-mocha ./test/e2e.js",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "hot-server": "node server.js",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.production.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "start": "electron .",
    "start-hot": "HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron .",
    "package": "NODE_ENV=production node package.js",
    "package-all": "npm run package -- --all"
  },
```